# Error with the code of finding the object with corrent argument

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a code for Auction task. There are 4 classes: *Item*,*Bid*,*Auction*,*Person*. 
*Item* contains:*name* of the Item,*description* of the Item,*minPrice* of the Item,LinkedList of *allBids*
*Auction* contains:LinkedList of *allItems*,LinkedList of *bidders*
*Bid* contains:*price* of the Bid,object *person* of the Person class
*Person* contains:*name* of the bidder.

So after this sho brifing I want to summaruize my problem. I provide my class diagramm if you have other kind of questions.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=19mjayMIWFRNygvzP2xIGEWVzZcKNXIZD

there is a `addBid(String itemName ,String nameOfBidder,long price)`
method in the *Auction* class which, should find the bidder from *bidder* LinkedList(if it dose not exist create it) then according the name of the Item find correct one and then using the *addBid* method from *Item* class add new bid in an item object.

There is a mistake in my code that when I am trying to find out an Item according its *itemName* it schould return me *NoSuchElementException* if no item object with such name exists. But every time I fail this check, actually I do not understand why.

I am trying to solve my problem by using different types of loops(foreach for example). But during a couple of days cann not solve it.

Here is my method from Auction class of addBid method

```
public void addBid(String ItemName, String nameOfBidder, long price) {

        if(ItemName==null||nameOfBidder==null){
            throw new NullPointerException("Name of the bidder cannot be null");
        }

        if(ItemName==""||nameOfBidder==""||price==0||price<0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name of the bidder cannot be empty");
        }

        for(Person p:bidders) {
            if (bidders.contains(p.getName()==nameOfBidder)) {
                for (Item i:allItems ) {
                    if(!(allItems.contains(i.getName()))){
                        throw new NoSuchElementException("There is no such Item in the Auction");
                    }
                    if(allItems.contains(i.getName()==ItemName)){
                        i.addBid(p,price);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                Person person = new Person(nameOfBidder);
                bidders.add(person);
                for (Item i:allItems ) {
                    if(!(allItems.contains(i.getName()))){
                        throw new NoSuchElementException("There is no such Item in the Auction");
                    }
                    if(allItems.contains(i.getName()==ItemName)){
                        i.addBid(person,price);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

And my Junit test where I a failing the last check(NoSuchElementException )

```
   public void testAddBidIllegalArgument() {
        a.registerItem(new Item("Clock", "Ancient clock", 1000));
        try {
            a.addBid("", "Max", 5);
            fail("Auction.addBid() should throw an IllegalArgumentException if the itemName argument is empty!");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }

        try {
            a.addBid("Clock", "", 5);
            fail("Auction.addBid() should throw an IllegalArgumentException if the nameOfBidder argument is empty!");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }

        try {
            a.addBid("Clock", "Max", 0);
            fail("Auction.addBid() should throw an IllegalArgumentException if the price argument is zero!");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }

        try {
            a.addBid("Clock", "Max", -1);
            fail("Auction.addBid() should throw an IllegalArgumentException if the price argument is negative!");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }

        try {
            a.addBid("New", "Max", 5);
            fail("Auction.addBid() should throw a NoSuchElementException if no item in the auction has the given name!");
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        }
    }
```

Please help me with my error! And help me to pass the last check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following conditions are not looking correct:

```
for(Person p:bidders) {
    // bidders holds Person objects and you are checking for boolean. p.getName() == nameOfBidder will evaluate to true. Perhaps you want to check for name equality first and then contains.
    if (bidders.contains(p.getName()==nameOfBidder)) {
   }
}

for (Item i:allItems ) {
    // allItems holds Item objects and you are checking by name string
    if(!(allItems.contains(i.getName()))){ 

    }
}
```

Also, the initial null and check conditions can be simplified.

Here you go, much simplified code:

```
public void addBid(String itemName, String nameOfBidder, double price) {
    if (itemName == null || nameOfBidder == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Name of the bidder cannot be null");
    }
    if (itemName.equals("") || nameOfBidder.equals("") || price <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name of the bidder cannot be empty");
    }
    Optional<Person> person = bidders.stream().filter(e -> e.getName().equals(nameOfBidder)).findAny();
    Optional<Item> item = items.stream().filter(e -> e.getName().equals(itemName)).findAny();
    if (person.isPresent()) {
        checkItemAndAddBid(item, person.get(), price);
    } else {
        Person newPerson = new Person(nameOfBidder);
        bidders.add(newPerson);
        System.out.println("Creating a new bidder: "+newPerson.getName());
        checkItemAndAddBid(item, newPerson, price);
    }
}

public void checkItemAndAddBid(Optional<Item> item, Person person, double price) {
    if (!item.isPresent()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("There is no such Item in the Auction");
    } else {
        item.get().addBid(person, price);
    }
}
```

The complete running sample code is available: [at github](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference/blob/master/java/misc/src/main/java/org/openapex/samples/misc/assorted/CondtionsAndLoop57233098.java)